# How to make multi-tenant app in azure ad available to other organizations/applications?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I have added a web application in Microsoft AZURE AD for accessing the Office 365 Exchange services  and enabled multi-tenant option. Now the problem is I want to make it available to other applications/organizations.

Currently I am able to install the app in the same domain.
But how will I be able to install this app into some other domain ?

Note : This is an unpublished app and I am trying to make it available to test in different domains.

Comment: What kind of app is it?

Comment: It is an application for accessing Office 365 Exchange services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ravi, with "unpublished" are you referring to the app catalog? As long as potential users can navigate to the application, even by following a direct link, at authentication time they will be given the opportunity to consent - which will result in the application being provisioned in their own organization. Just share with your testers a direct link to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Set the multi tenant option in Azure Portal to true. You can let your customers to get the build app from an FTP site until you deploy it to marketplace.
If it is an outlook app, you can install it as an exchange app in your customer o365 tenant.

[image]