# Azur AD - Multi tenancy application available to other organizations

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've created a multi tenancy application so I could use the SSO options it gives me.
When trying to sign in with a user outside the domain of the app I get the following error:

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier `<MY_APP_NAME>` was not found in the directory `<I_GUESS_THE_USERS_DIRECTORY_ID?>`. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577283/how-to-make-multi-tenant-app-in-azure-ad-available-to-other-organizations-applic) it's suppose to work without me having to do anything.
But, is it? what me or the organization should do in order to complete the process?

Comment: How have you configured authentication on your app side?

Comment: @juunas can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also provision a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) of your multi-tenant app in the target tenant. A detailed guide is available [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant#service-principal-provisioning-for-new-tenants-onboarding-process).

Answer (score 0):

There are four simple steps to convert your application into an Azure Ad Multi-tenant app:

1.Update your application registration to be multi-tenant

2.Update your code to send requests to the /common endpoint

3.Update your code to handle multiple issuer values

4.Understand user and admin consent and make appropriate code changes

Reference:

[How to: Sign in any Azure Active Directory user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)

[Build a multi-tenant daemon with the Microsoft identity platform endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp/build-multi-tenant-daemon-aad/)

Comment: I have already followed these steps. My question is, why does it ask the admin of the user that's signing in to install my app in their directory.

Comment: @Ben If you received the error message shown in your original question, then step 1 likely has not been done. Can you confirm you did this?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I have done step 1 as described in the referenced link. However, when I passed in the `issuer` field in the SAML request the `Application ID URI` value (in App Registrations -> Expose an API) instead of a random identifier I set in the SAML sign on properties, I got a different error saying my app hasn't requested 'AAD graph' permissions. does this make sense ? does an admin of the signing in user directory have to give certain permissions to my app? (my app is in a different domain)

Comment: Ah, so that's a different issue. In the app registration for your app, go to "API permissions" and add "User.Read" for the Microsoft Graph. When users from a different tenant sign in to your app, they (or an admin, if they aren't allowed to) will need to consent to sharing their profile details with your app.

Answer (score 0):

So in the scenario like above is it not required to "Register the Application all of the Active Directories" from where the Users from different tenant may login to the Application ?

If not required to register what is the work around?